# Textview Single click not working

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, ellipsis

I have made custom list view in which i have also added a textview.I want to expend all the text which is being ellipsed so for that I have also set onClickListener on textView but when i click on textView it does nothing but on second click it perform my functionality.Here is my code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final CruunNotificationModel cruun = userDetails.get(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.imagewithlist, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.userComments = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.userCommentsTextView);
        holder.userName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.userNameTextView);
        holder.dateTime = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.dateTimeTextView);
        holder.userImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.userImageImageView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.userComments.setText(cruun.getComments());
    holder.userName.setText(cruun.getUserName());
    holder.dateTime.setText(cruun.getDataAndTime());
    holder.userImage.setImageResource(cruun.getImageId());
    holder.userComments.setFocusable(false);
    holder.userComments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            holder.userComments.setEllipsize(null);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.userImageLayout);
            holder.userComments.setLayoutParams(lParams);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView userComments;
    TextView userName;
    TextView dateTime;
    ImageView userImage;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code ? Please post some more code of your adapter class.

Comment: pls post some more code..

Comment: I have posted and added my getView method of adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line `holder.userComments.setFocusable(false);` from your `getView` and then check.

Comment: I have removed as u suggested but still having same problem.

Comment: Can you show your layout code ? Make sure that you have not implemented the `ListView` Item click listener. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Yes I have but click listener on listView is working and when i click on text the only the textView listener works and when i click on listView then listener of listview works but in case of textView it performs function on second time click.

Comment: You can not handle ListView item click and its individual items click at the same time. You need to handle either or.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u to convert ur TextView to Button in xml & set its background to transparent !

This will be seen as a TextView & u can perform ur code furthur